# parsing argument to python script

Tags: python

I want to create a script like this

```
./myscript.py -g parser -a parserapp
```

and whenever the script is missing one option such as `./myscript.py -g parser`, it will print out usage and exit the script

```
The script should be: ./myscript.py -g parser -a parserapp
```

So, my question is how can I check if option `-a` or`-g` is  missing; so, it can print out the usage for the script and exit.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Look at existing modules already dealing with command line options, such as `argparse`

Comment: Yep, argparse is the way. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I did, and there seem to be nothing that can help me to check if my option is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-g", "--gggg", help="g parameter",required=True)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--aaaa", help="a parameter",required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.g, args.a
```

When you run it with -h it will show help:

```
~#:python myscript.py -h
usage: myscript.py [-h] -g GGGG -a AAAA

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -g GGGG, --gggg GGGG  g parameter
  -a AAAA, --aaaa AAAA  a parameter
```

If you miss a parameter it will print error:

```
myscript.py: error: argument -g/--gggg is required
```

Answer (score 2):

For your need argparse can check wether an argument is missing or not like this :

```
 import argparse
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My Super Script')
 parser.add_argument(
        '--parser', '-p',
        required=True,
        help='Parser Type'
        )
 parser.add_argument(
        '--application', '-a',
        required=True,
        help='Application Name'
        )
 args = parser.parse_args()
```

By default argparse will consider a named argument optional unless you specify `required=True`
If the two args are not provided this will print a default help.
[ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing of parameters can be done with optparse or argparse. You can make nifty help options and so on. It's also easy to make different kinds of parameters to be accepted.

Use argparse: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argparse` module.
For Python3.x, you can look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html).
For Python2.x, you can look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html).

Apart from `argparse`, you can also use `getopt` module.
Use `getopt`:
https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getopt.html(Python3.x)
              https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html(Python2.x)